# Scheduler doesn't work when I close app

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I need to write a scheduler which will update app data every 5 min I found reciple

Create receiver and IntentService but they doesn't work when I close the app. In manifest it looks like an application sections

```
 <receiver android:name=".components.UpdateReceiver" android:process=":remote">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".components.UpdateService"/>
```

Code of receiver class:

```
public final class UpdateReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
    startWakefulService(context, service);
}

public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,UpdateReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    long interval = 5 * 60 *1000;

    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    interval,
             interval, alarmIntent);
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, UpdateReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

}
```

In my splash activity I created UpdateReceiver and called set Alarm method. All works great, but when I close the app it doesn't work. I tested on a android 6.0 device maybe problems is there. I found a lot of tutorials almost all are same, but I can't understand where is error?

Answer (score 0):

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running.

Your reciver is not being called because google changed the way you ask permission on API level 23.

**How do we ask permissions?**
Inside activity visible lifecycle methods (e.g onCreate / onResume):

```
int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACQUIRE_WAKE_LOCK = 200; //Can be any number that represent OK result code
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK
```

},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACQUIRE_WAKE_LOCK
);
And get permission request result inside `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACQUIRE_WAKE_LOCK: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission granted! 
            } else {

                // permission denied by user
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see a list of permission you need to ask that way [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en).
I also recommend read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) & [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html).

Comment: READ_CONTACTS for what I need it?

Comment: @Abbath Edited to be question specific*

Comment: I changed the permission string from "READ_CONTACTS" to "WAKE_LOCK" which is the permission you need to use WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Comment: but WAKE_LOCK is not dangerous permission.